# Why aren't set literals O(1) for "in" operations?

Tags: python, set, tuples, literals, membership

It's pretty common to test a lot of constants against a variable by doing

```
if x in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'):
```

rather than

```
if x == 'foo' or x == 'bar' or x == 'baz':
```

I've seen a lot of "use `{'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}` instead of `('foo', 'bar', 'baz')` for O(1) performance," which makes sense, but testing shows pretty strange results.

```
%timeit 1 in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
27.6 ns ± 2.35 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%timeit 10 in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
136 ns ± 4.04 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%timeit 0 in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
186 ns ± 26.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Why is the lookup for set literals not constant time?

Comment: I don't understand what you're measuring. If you're always using sets of size 10, then what do you mean when you say "it scales linearly"? Linearly with what (apparently not the number of items in the set as that always seems to be 10)?

Comment: @sepp2k Linearly with which item I'm checking. Basically, when I can stop checking. For example, if I'm checking if the first item is in the sequence, I can do only one check and stop there. If I'm checking for the last item, I need to go through the entire sequence before I can stop. If I'm checking for a non-existent item, again the entire sequence must be exhausted.

Comment: You're no just checking membership here, you're checking set creation _and_ membership checking at the same time. Have you tried pre-creating tuples/lists/sets, then only timing membership checking? And preferably with thousands of elements rather than 10?

Comment: Try larger sets. It's often faster to just do a linear search for small sizes rather than calculating hashes etc. Maybe python has this optimized by set-size.

Comment: I tested with a set literal of size 10000. I'll put it in my question.

Comment: Stop coupling the creation of the set (regardless of its inception via literal or otherwise) with measuring access. Constructing the set is necessarily linear to its size and dwarfs the lookup. Test JUST the lookup.

Comment: @deets Sorry if my question came across as unclear, but what I'm asking is why set literals are not the same as sets created with `set()`.

Comment: Set literals result in sets just as the `set()` constructor does. The reason why you are observing a difference between `{1, 2, 3}` and `set([1, 2, 3])` is because the latter first constructs a list which is then used to make a set (and your measurement includes the construction).

Comment: @mkrieger1 Well, apparently, using `{...}` is not having the same effect as creating a set on the spot... Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That's right, and I (and several others here) have already explained why. (`{...}` creates a set "on the spot". `set([...])` *does not*, it creates a list first, and then a set. Note the `[]`. Either way, the resulting sets are the same.)

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sorry, my original question was unclear, I've changed it now. I'm mostly concerned with set literals acting like tuples. Is Python doing some optimization or something?

Comment: As I mention in my answer, CPython does optimize set creation in some situations where it can tell a constant `frozenset` instance is just as good as a regular mutable set. But it's not obvious to me if what you're doing would qualify (I don't actually know all the situations where the optimization can run).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set lookup is on average an O(1) operation. It should not consistently change performance with what element of the set you check for, except randomly to a certain extent as some values may have hash collisions with other values and so take longer to be found. The time differences you're seeing to look up different values in your small sets are almost certainly coincidences, or noise that you're mistaking for data.

Note that you're not just timing set membership in your tests. You're also creating a new set each time, and that is usually an O(N) operation (where N is the number of values in the set). In some special situations, a set literal may be created in O(1) time as the Python compiler does an optimization to replace the mutable `set` object with an immutable `frozenset` object, which it has computed in advance as a constant. That only happens in situation where the compiler expects to be recreating the object a whole bunch of times, and where it can tell that no reference to the set object can leak out of the area of code its running. For instance, a set used in a `if` clause of a comprehension or generator expression may get the constant treatment:

```
[foo(x) for x in some_iterable if x in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9}]
```

In recent versions of CPython, the set literal here will always refer to a constant `frozenset` that doesn't need to be recreated for each `x` value yielded from `some_iterable`. But you probably shouldn't rely upon this behavior, as other Python interpreters, and even other versions of CPython may not perform the same optimization.

This can't explain what you're seeing in your timings though. I suspect that there's some artifact in your environment that explains the issue, or it may just be random chance that the smallest value in the set happens to not have any hash collisions while the last one (by coincidence) has several. If you test other values in the set, you'll probably get a small range of different timings. But that range won't tend to vary much with the number of set elements, it should be fairly similar for every size of set (there may be small differences, but much less than a factor of N).

Try a more specific test (with set creation factored out), like this:

```
import timeit, random

big_set = set(range(1000000))

for x in random.sample(range(1000000), 10):
    print('looking up', x, 'took', timeit.timeit(lambda: x in big_set), 'seconds')
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, couple of things here.

1. `set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])` is super-slow, because it may build list first. I guess, there's some optimizations in 3.7+, but anyway. Set literals is faster because of this.
2. "checking for the first member is even a bit slower" – the thing about sets – it's not magically `O(1)`. Set member check is hash + modulo + comparison of hash + fallbacks for collision/deletion. There's no such thing as "first member".
3. Tuples outperform sets on small data – because sets leverages a lot of machinery. It's `O(1)`, but constant is higher than value of `O(N)` on some range. Profile your code with, like, 10**6-length, you'll see the difference
4. Timing with literals is weird idea, usually fast membership check leverages already created containers:

   ```
   t = tuple(range(10**6))
   s = set(range(10**6))
   %timeit 999999 in t
   11.9 ms ± 92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

   %timeit 999999 in s
   52 ns ± 0.538 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
   ```

---

Side note on testing asymptotic complexity – you should always check the magnitude of growth, raw data means nothing. I.e.

```
x = 1; t = tuple(range(10**x)); s = set(range(10**x))
%timeit (-1) in t
168 ns ± 22.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
%timeit (-1) in s
38.3 ns ± 0.46 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

x = 2; t = tuple(range(10**x)); s = set(range(10**x))
%timeit (-1) in t
1.1 µs ± 17.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit (-1) in s
37.7 ns ± 0.101 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

x = 4; t = tuple(range(10**x)); s = set(range(10**x))
%timeit (-1) in t
107 µs ± 860 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit (-1) in s
39 ns ± 1.66 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

x = 6; t = tuple(range(10**x)); s = set(range(10**x))
%timeit (-1) in t
10.8 ms ± 114 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit (-1) in s
38 ns ± 0.333 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

so you can clearly see what is linearity vs constant here.

Comment: I apologize if my original question was unclear, but I am asking why set literals behave differently from sets created beforehand or sets created using `set()`. I do realize that set membership check is hashing, but why is checking for the first element faster for a set literal? Shouldn't it be the same across the set?

Comment: It's not "behave differently". When you're profiling line of code that _creates_ set, it's not about membership, mostly, it's about container creation and memory alloc. See p.1 – literals is faster than `set()`. Creating set beforehand pulls all this time out of profiling, altogether.

Comment: Sorry, my original question was unclear, I've changed it now. I'm mostly concerned with set literals acting like tuples. Is Python doing some optimization or something?

Answer (score 2):

You're testing both the construction of the set *and* the searching. Let's try the experiments again, but only constructing `a` once. First, here's a tuple:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'a = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)' -- '0 in a'
10000000 loops, best of 5: 22.6 nsec per loop
```

Searching for the last element is slower:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'a = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)' -- '9 in a'
2000000 loops, best of 5: 136 nsec per loop
```

As is searching for missing values:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'a = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)' -- '-1 in a'
2000000 loops, best of 5: 132 nsec per loop
```

`set.__contains__` is *much* better once the object is constructed:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}' -- '0 in a'
10000000 loops, best of 5: 26.3 nsec per loop
```

As expected, ordering doesn't matter:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}' -- '9 in a'
10000000 loops, best of 5: 26.1 nsec per loop
```

Neither does checking for missing values:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}' -- '-1 in a'
10000000 loops, best of 5: 26.4 nsec per loop
```

Comment: Sorry, my original question was unclear, I've changed it now. I'm mostly concerned with set literals acting like tuples. Is Python doing some optimization or something?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get your results:

```
python -m timeit "(-1) in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0238 usec per loop

python -m timeit "0 in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0235 usec per loop

python -m timeit "9 in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0208 usec per loop
```

As for your question regarding the difference in the `set()` creation and `{}` creation you can see the difference in the bytecode:

Set literal:

```
from dis import dis
print(dis("9 in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}"))
```

Output:

```
          0 LOAD_CONST               0 (9)
          2 LOAD_CONST              10 (frozenset({0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}))
          4 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
          6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Using a function:

```
print(dis("9 in set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])"))
```

Output:

```
          0 LOAD_CONST               0 (9)
          2 LOAD_NAME                0 (set)
          4 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
          6 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
          8 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
         10 LOAD_CONST               4 (3)
         12 LOAD_CONST               5 (4)
         14 LOAD_CONST               6 (5)
         16 LOAD_CONST               7 (6)
         18 LOAD_CONST               8 (7)
         20 LOAD_CONST               9 (8)
         22 LOAD_CONST               0 (9)
         24 BUILD_LIST              10
         26 CALL_FUNCTION            1
         28 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
         30 RETURN_VALUE
```

Both build a `set`, but python is immediately able to recognize the literal set as a literal (and optimizes to build a frozenset since it knows there isn't need for any addition and removal), while it needs to build a list, load the `set` function, and then call the function on the list. However this difference is only in set creation. It will not affect the `in` operation.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be confused about the meaning of algorithmic complexity -- you haven't tested that characteristic.  *Complexity* describes the asymptotic time requirement as the input size tends to infinity.

Your testing is for only one input size: 10 elements.  You *do* test for best and worst cases.  however, to work toward for the algorithmic complexity, you'd need to extract the initialization step from the timing, and then compare performance across a variety of input sizes: perhaps powers of 10, ranging from 10 to 10**12.

Comment: By the way, I did test for larger cases, up to 10000 with a set literal, it's just I didn't want to paste the entire literal in... I got similar results, which is why I'm only including the minimum reproducible result.

Comment: You don't use a literal: generate the set with something such as `set(range(10 ** n))`, in a loop that runs `n` over your desired range.

Comment: I apologize if it came across as unclear, but my question is why aren't set literals treated as normal sets?

Comment: Sorry, my original question was unclear, I've changed it now. I'm mostly concerned with set literals acting like tuples. Is Python doing some optimization or something?